# How to alphabetically sort the values in a many-to-many django-admin box?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-admin, many-to-many

I have a simple model like this one:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
   surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='artists', blank=True)
   bio = models.TextField(blank=True)  

class Images(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
   img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Well, I started to insert some Artists and then I went to the Images insert form. I found that the many-to-many artist box is unsorted:

- Mondino Aldo
- Aliprandi Bernardo
- Rotella Mimmo
- Corpora Antonio

Instead of:

- Aliprandi Bernardo
- Corpora Antonio
- Mondino Aldo
- Rotella Mimmo

How can I solve this issue?
Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.

Matteo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set [`ordering`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) on the Article's inner `Meta` class.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ....

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['surname', 'name']
```

Comment: Don't! This has as performance implications for your whole app (see the warning in the linked django doc). I would recommend using Daniel's better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1474175/758345