# Django Admin: Ordering of ForeignKey and ManyToManyField relations referencing User

Tags: python, django, sorting, admin, user-profile

I have an application that makes use of Django's `UserProfile` to extend the built-in Django `User` model.  Looks a bit like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    # Local Stuff
    image_url_s = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    image_url_m = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    # Admin
    class Admin: pass
```

I have added a new class to my model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='manager')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

And it is registered into the Admin:

```
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'manager')

admin.site.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```

Alas, in the admin inteface, when I go to select a manager from the drop-down box, or set team members via the multi-select field, they are ordered by the User numeric ID.  For the life of me, I can not figure out how to get these sorted.

I have a similar class with:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']
```

That works great!  But I don't "own" the `User` class, and when I try this trick in `UserAdmin`:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['username']
```

I get:

`django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:`
`events.userprofile: "ordering" refers to "username", a field that doesn't exist.`

`user.username` doesn't work either.  I could specify, like `image_url_s` if I wanted to . . . how can I tell the admin to sort my lists of users by `username`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way would be to define a custom form to use for your Team model in the admin, and override the `manager` field to use a queryset with the correct ordering:

```
from django import forms

class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manager = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.order_by('username'))

    class Meta:
        model = Team

class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'manager')
    form = TeamForm
```

Comment: Since django 1.8 you also need `fields = '__all__'` inside `Class Meta`.

Answer (score 38):

This

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['username']
```

should be

```
    ordering = ['user__username']
```

if it's in your UserProfile admin class. That'll stop the exception, but I don't think it helps you.

Ordering the User model as you describe is quite tricky, but see http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6089#comment:8 for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

This might be dangerous for some reason, but this can be done in one line in your project's `models.py` file:

```
User._meta.ordering=["username"]
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the only working solution was to use [Proxy Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). As stated in the documentation, you can create own proxy models for even built-in models and customize anything like in regular models:

```
class OrderedUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        ordering = ["username"]
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

After that, in your model just change Foreign Key to:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(OrderedUser, unique=True)
```

or even more suitable

```
user = models.OneToOneField(OrderedUser, unique = True, parent_link = True)
```