# django admin order by alphabet

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i am using django-admin, and i have a model as following. it shows as a dropdown list in the admin. how can i order it by alphabet? instead of default user ID?

```
user= models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you describe is, according to Django core devs, a feature, not a bug. In the beginning, Django ordered the `User` field alphabetically, but this resulted in a performance issue for *really* big sites (namely [Pownce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pownce) at the time) with hundreds of thousands of users. But instead of asking the few *huge* Django websites to implement a workaround, the ordering was simply [removed](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/7806), and now every site that has models with a `ForeignKey` to `User` has a usability problem.

I posted an [ugly workaround](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6089#comment:8) on the Django issue tracker about a year ago. Daniel Roseman posted a similar (and IMHO better) solution in another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474135/django-admin-ordering-of-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-relations-referencing-us).

Comment: do u know type object 'CollaboratorForm' has no attribute 'fields'

Answer (score 2):

Why not at the level model?

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['field',]
```

Or at the level admin?

```
class Admin:
    ordering       = ('field',)
```

Comment: simply because it is django.contrib, so you should not change it this way. you can but this is not a good idea to modify library for the single project.

Comment: Sorry? I'm not talking about modifying any library. I was thinking on the proxy-models as stated in the documentation: "The standard User model has no ordering defined on it (intentionally; sorting is expensive and we don't want to do it all the time when we fetch users). You might want to regularly order by the username attribute when you use the proxy..."

Comment: But then - you will have different model in different namespace. So your foreign key will be to a different model.

Comment: Yep, to the proxy-model. Clear enough, nop? No relation to your first comment, anyway,

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom form for your model and assign it to your ModelAdmin subclass -- you can override the ordering for the ModelChoiceField in the form's `__init__`. For example:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # Other model fields ...

# forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.order_by('first_name', 'last_name')

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.forms import MyModelForm

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
    # Other admin attributes ...

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelForm)
```

Comment: do u know why i always got "type object 'CollaboratorForm' has no attribute 'fields'"
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Django provides much better way of doing this. It's even in their documentation
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Answer (score 0):

If you have not only 5 but a decent amount of users, it might make sense to change the Admin to use `raw_id_fields` for the user selection. That way, the users will be displayed in their own list view, allowing for filtering and sorting.

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ['user']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily sort in your `admin.py` relevant Admin class.

Let's say your Admin class is the following:

```
@admin.register(UserStuff)
class UserStuffAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'other', 'fields']
    ordering = ['user']
```

The line `ordering = ['user']` will order by the `user` field. Alphabetically or numerically, depending on the field. Uses the field's normal ordering method. You can also do `ordering = ['-user']` which will sort in descending order.

**Source:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering