# Ordering related model values in django-rest admin view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-3.0

I want to see this view with the **features list** sorted alphabetically.

[image: django-rest view]

The model from the view above comes from is *AircraftModel*.

**models.py**:

```
class AircraftModelFeature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AircraftModel(models.Model):
    features_list = models.ManyToManyField(AircraftModelFeature)
    # ... other stuff ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AircraftModelFeatureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AircraftModelFeature
        fields = "__all__"

class AircraftModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    features_list = AircraftModelFeatureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # ...other stuff...

    class Meta:
        model = AircraftModel
        fields = ['id', 'features_list',] # there are more fields, omitted
```

**views.py**

```
class AircraftModelFeatureViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
    queryset = AircraftModelFeature.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = AircraftModelFeatureSerializer
    
class AircraftModelViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
    queryset = AircraftModel.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = AircraftModelSerializer
```

So, how can I make that list sorted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering a Many-To-Many field in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630163/ordering-a-many-to-many-field-in-django-admin)

Comment: It doesn't, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com), I've found the solution: modifying the Model class that's being used by the Admin Django app. The file i had to edit was admin.py.

**admin.py** before:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pubapi.models import AircraftModelOptional

admin.site.register(AircraftModelOptional)
```

**admin.py** after:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pubapi.models import AircraftModelOptional

class AircraftModelOptionalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['name']

admin.site.register(AircraftModelOptional, AircraftModelOptionalAdmin)
```

What I obtained:

[image: result]

As written [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) it's possible to edit the Model being used by the Admin Django app.

As written [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering) it's possible to order the list by Model fields.