# Django Problem : I want to see reverse order in django admin many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my `model.py` code

```
class Question(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
class TestSeries(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    all_question=models.ManyToManyField(MyQuestion)
```

When i open my admin panel on test series
previous added are shown in order : Oldest first

I want to see that in newest first manner.

Comment: OP's models don't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things OP needs to do

1. [Store in the models when the object was created / updated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3429878/7109869).
2. Order based on the creation date. To do so, one can add to the model a Meta option named [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) or define a custom form to be used in the Django Admin. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474135/7109869), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3630163/7109869).

Comment: We need to apply ordering = creation date , in TestSeries admin register or Question admin register . we want to order based on creation date under test series , when selecting questions

Comment: @RajSubh add in both, it's a good standard as well.