# Declaring a custom form field removes the add icon

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I followed the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474135/django-admin-ordering-of-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-relations-referencing-u) to alter the order of items in a foreign key select list in my Django admin.  The reordering works great, but the little add icon has disappeared from after the select list.  How can I get it back?

```
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    publisher = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Publisher.objects.order_by('name'))
    platform = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Platform.objects.order_by('platform'))

    class Meta:
        model = Game

class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','platform','publisher','age_rating','buy_date','pub_date')
    form = GameForm

admin.site.register(Game, GameAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form overrides admin application fields `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` widget

To prevent this `queryset` should be changed in `__init__` method

```
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['publisher'].queryset = Publisher.objects.order_by('name')
        self.fields['platform'].queryset = Platform.objects.order_by('platform')
```